# sql developer error ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Representatives(

ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

State CHAR(2) NOT NULL,

District NUMBER NOT NULL CHECK(District>=1 AND District<=30),

Party VARCHAR2(30),

LastName VARCHAR2(20),

Firstname VARCHAR2(20),

StartOfTerm DATE,

EndOfTerm DATE,

SenRank VARCHAR2 CHECK(senRank IN ('junior', 'senior')),

Gender CHAR(1) CHECK(Gender IN ('M', 'F')),

Birthdate DATE,

FOREIGN KEY(State) REFERENCES States(State),

FOREIGN KEY(Party) REFERENCES Parties(Party)

);
```

**Error report -
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
*Cause:

*Action:**

Can't find the error can someone please point me to the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is a missing length on `varchar2()`:

```
CREATE TABLE Representatives (
    ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    State CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    District NUMBER NOT NULL CHECK(District>=1 AND District<=30),
    Party VARCHAR2(30),
    LastName VARCHAR2(20),
    Firstname VARCHAR2(20),
    StartOfTerm DATE,
    EndOfTerm DATE,
    SenRank VARCHAR2(255) CHECK (senRank IN ('junior', 'senior')),
    -----------------^
    Gender CHAR(1) CHECK (Gender IN ('M', 'F')),
    Birthdate DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (State) REFERENCES States(State),
    FOREIGN KEY (Party) REFERENCES Parties(Party)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f796c8559ee669cbf5863300f12e56f9) is a db<>fiddle, without the foreign key declarations.

Answer (score 0):

> SenRank VARCHAR2 CHECK(senRank IN ('junior', 'senior')),

You forgot to mention the length of `VARCHAR2` data type in the `SenRank` column. Add an appropriate length and it should work just fine:

```
SenRank VARCHAR2(25) CHECK(senRank IN ('junior', 'senior'))
```